# Android launch application multiple times on an NFC tag discovered

Tags: android, fragment, nfc

Android launch application multiple times on an NFC tag discovered. I tried using the answer in this link [Android launch activity multiple times on an NFC tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687482/android-launch-activity-multiple-times-on-an-nfc-tag/41868894?noredirect=1#comment70922103_41868894). but it says resources not found.
I am reading the tag from a fragment. Any help.
This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.atsl.touch">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is my fragments onResume()

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent intent =getActivity().getIntent();
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter[] { };
        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(getContext());
        String action = intent.getAction();
        boolean cardMatched=false;

        Tag tag=null;
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Blahhhhh",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            tag = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            tappedCard=new Card();
            tappedCard.setCardId(MainActivity.bytesToHexString(tag.getId()));
            //tag = (Tag)intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            String[] techList = tag.getTechList();
            ////////////+___________________________________________
            ////////////+___________________________________________
            if(tag == null){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "tag == null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Card cc=new Card();
                String tagId= MainActivity.bytesToHexString(tag.getId());
                cc.setCardId(tagId);
                dbHelper=new DBHelper(getContext());

                ArrayList<Card> checkList=dbHelper.getAllCards();
                if(checkList.size()>0)
                {
                    for(Card d:checkList)
                    {
                        if (cc.equals(d))
                        {
                            cardMatched=true;
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Card Matched !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            showCardDetails(cc.getCardId());
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!cardMatched)
                    {
                         imgBusCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                         showDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Card Not Matched !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        CustomDialogAddCard customDialogAddCard =new CustomDialogAddCard(getActivity(),"T",cc);
                        customDialogAddCard.show();
                        showCardDetails(cc.getCardId());
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No cards found !!!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CustomDialogAddCard customDialogAddCard =new CustomDialogAddCard(getActivity(),"T",cc);
                    customDialogAddCard.show();
                    showCardDetails(cc.getCardId());
                }
            }

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),
                    "onResume() : " + action,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The problem is when i run the application and hold an nfc tag near the phone app starts a new instance of the application. it doesn't detect the tag in the initial instance.

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: i edited the question